# Delphi -How to recognize user voice inputs and convert it to windows commands

Tags: delphi

I am currently working with "Speech To Text" Desktop Application, I know how to do 'Text To Speech' using Microsoft Speech Object Library but, how to do 'Speech To Text' or 'speech to Command'.

```
Example 1: I say "Hello World", the Application Write 'Hello World' in for Ex: Note Pad or in 'TMemo'.
Example 2: i say "Open Note Pad", the Application will open the windows note pad.
```

I just need a simple tip to start with, also i would like to provide me with some properties or methods.

If this idea cannot be made with '**Microsoft Speech Object Library**' then please guide me through some other way.
Please I really need some help, I haven't find any examples online.

Comment: Start with looking at the speech / voice recognition that comes with Windows. It has some limitations and differs between versions.

Comment: What is your specific question

Comment: how to handle user voice from microphone and convert it to command

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice article about usage of Speech API 5.1 in Delphi: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29583 Also, there is good documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723627(v%3dvs.85) Windows 10 has updated API, but it can't be used on previous versions of windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition

Comment: thank you, but i already saw Delphi article about using Microsoft Speech it seems like jumpy, i didn't understand a lot, i hoped that if you give me some code handling few user commands it will be a nice start for me.

Comment: Sorry @halocedark, but SO is about technical answers to specific programming problems, not providing a "nice start" of the tutorial kind that you seem to be expecting.

Comment: i already done a project in VB of Speech Recognition as an answer of my question, but i just need the components that does the same in Delphi